# Google Drive Api V3 - retreive all folders and files with it's childrens as treeview

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, google-apps-script

is there any way to retrieve folders and files from google drive with its subfolders or children's at one shot using Google API v3 client?  Below is my code that I'm using to retrieve right now which I only get the first layer data. Please, anyone, advise me with this. Appreciated it if meet my requirements.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post your code as images.

Comment: It is not possible to retrieve all files in one shot. List files api fetches data in pages. Max page size is 1000. See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all the files, you will have to use `Files:list` method. However, the maximum number of results that can be returned per page is **1000**.

In order to retrieve all the other remaining files, you will have to make use of the `nextPageToken` parameter.

According to the [Drive API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list):

> `nextPageToken` > The page token for the next page of files. This will be absent if the end of the files list has been reached. If the token is rejected for any reason, it should be discarded, and pagination should be restarted from the first page of results.

Also, depending on the exact `corpora` parameter you pass to the request, the `incompleteSearch` parameter *might* be of help as well.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).

Comment: It is really useful. It really helps me. Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real old script I wrote pre v8:

The may be stuff in here that's not part of the script but I've included everything.

Code.gs:

```
var GStorage = '';
var folderID = "Storage Folder Id"
var GFlag = 0;
function onOpen()
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Tools')
            .addItem('My Drive Directory Listing','runtraverseFolder')
            .addItem('Clear Dirlist','clearDirlist')
            .addToUi();
}

function runtraverseFolder()
{
  var dirlist = loadDirlist();
  var html1 = '<html><head></head><body><div class="cntrls"><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\
  <input type="button" value="Delete Cached Listing & Start Over" onClick="google.script.run.clearDirlist();" /></div><br />';
  var html2 = '</div><div class="cntrls"><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close()" />\
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Delete Cached Listing & Start Over" onClick="google.script.run.clearDirlist();" />\
  <br /></body></html>';
  if(dirlist)
  {
    dispStatus('Stored MyDrive Directory List', html1 + GStorage + html2, 800, 600);
  }
  else
  {
    GStorage ='<style>\
    .tab0{margin-left:0px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab1{margin-left:50px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab2{margin-left:100px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab3{margin-left:150px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab4{margin-left:200px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab5{margin-left:250px;font-weight:750;}\
    .tab6{margin-left:300px;font-weight:750;}\
    .file{color:#d81840;}\
    .contrls{padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}\
    .timestmp {width: 200px;margin-left:5px;padding:10px 0px 5px 50px;background-color:rgba(121, 25, 0, 0.36);color:white;}</style>';
    GFlag = 0;
    traverseFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
    saveDirlist();
    dispStatus('Current MyDrive Directory Listing', html1 + GStorage + html2, 1000, 600);
    
  }
}

function traverseFolder(folderObj) 
{
  GStorage += '<p class="tab' + GFlag++ + '">' +  folderObj.getName() +  ', <span style="color:black;font-size:8px;"><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id='+ folderObj.getId() +'" target="_blank" >&nbsp;Open</a></span></p>';
  var subs = folderObj.getFolders();
  var files =  folderObj.getFiles();
  if(files)
  {
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
      var fi = files.next();;
      GStorage += '<p class="tab' + GFlag + ' file">' + fi.getName()  + ', <span style="color:black;font-size:8px;"><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id='+ fi.getId() +'" target="_blank" >&nbsp;Open</a></span></p>';
    }
  }
  while (subs.hasNext()) 
  {
    traverseFolder(subs.next());
  }
  GFlag--;
}

function saveDirlist()
{
  var filename = 'CurrentDirectoryListing';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var fldrname = fldr.getName();
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var targetFound = false;
  var timeStamp = '<div class="timestmp">' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + '</div>';
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      targetFound = true;
      fi.setContent(timeStamp + GStorage);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Directory Listing was updated using: ' + target);    }
  }
  if(!targetFound)
  {
    var created = fldr.createFile('CurrentDirectoryListing',timeStamp + GStorage);
    if(created)
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( 'Directory Listing was stored here: ' + fldr.getName() + '/' + created.getName());
    }
    else
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Unknown Error: Directory List was not stored');
    }
  }
}

function loadDirlist()
{
  var filename = 'CurrentDirectoryListing';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var targetFound = false;
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      targetFound = true;
      GStorage = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Directory Listing was retreived from: ' + fldr.getName() + '/' + target);
    }
  }
  return targetFound;
}

function clearDirlist()
{
  var filename = 'CurrentDirectoryListing';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var targetFound = false;
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      targetFound = true;
      fldr.removeFile(fi);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('File: ' + filename + ' was removed from: ' + fldr.getName() + '/' + target);
    }
  }
  return targetFound;
}
```

Utility.gs:

```
function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
// Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 250;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
} 

function getTriggers()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
  var title = "All My Current Triggers";
  var msg = '';
  if(triggers)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++)
    {
      msg+= 'Triggers[' + i + '] = ' + '<br />';
      msg+='EventType = ' + triggers[i].getEventType() + '<br />HandlerFunction = ' + triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() + '<br />TriggerSource = '  + triggers[i].getTriggerSource() + '<br />TriggerSourceID = ' + triggers[i].getTriggerSourceId() + '<br />TriggerUniqueId = ' + triggers[i].getUniqueId() +'<br /><br />';
    }
    dispStatus(title,msg,800,500);
  }
  else
  {
    dispStatus('All My Current Trigger','No Trigger',800,500);
  }
}
```

test.gs: (not sure if this is even used)

```
function test()
{
  var prompt ='';
  if(prompt)
  {
    var S = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('7 comma separated values A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5]  A[6] is stop 1,1,1,1,1,1,1');
  }
  else
  {
    var S = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('7 comma separated values A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5] 1,1,1,1,1,1,1');
  }
    
  var A = S.getResponseText().split(',');
  
  if(A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5])
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It\'s true.');
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It\'s false.');
  }
  if(A[6]==1)
  {
    test();
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}

function test1()
{
  //(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToCheck1, columnToCheck2, columnToCheck3 && sheet.getName() == sheetToSort)
  //var title = 'Evaluate (i==j, k, l && m==n) = result';
  var title = 'Evaluate (i==j, k, l) = result';
  var msg='';
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    var j=0;
    {
      var k=1;
      {
        var l=2;
        {
          var m=0;
          {
            var n=0;
            {
              if(n==j, k, l )
              {
                result='<span style="color:red;">true</span>';
              }
              else
              {
                result='<span style="color:black;">false</span>';
              }
              //msg += '( ' + i + ' == ' + j + ', ' + k + ', ' + l + ' && ' + m + ' == ' + n + ' ) = ' + result +'<br />';
              msg += '( ' + i + ' == ' + j + ', ' + k + ', ' + l + ' ) = ' + result +'<br />';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  dispStatus(title,msg,600,500);
}

function do_onEdit(e) 
{
  dispStatus('Do On Edit', 'At the beginning of do_onEdit',400,200);
  var sheetToSort = "Sheet2"; // name of sheet to be sorted
  var columnToCheck1 = 2; // column to check for edits
  var columnToCheck2 = 3; // second column to be checked for edits
  var columnToCheck3 = 6;
  var columnToCheck4 = 10;
  var columnToCheck5 = 11;
  var columnToCheck6 = 12;
  var columnToCheck7 = 13;
  var columnToCheck8 = 14;
  var columnToSortBy = 16; // column to sort by; A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var rangeToSort = "A1:P150"; // range of values to be sorted

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToCheck1, columnToCheck2, columnToCheck3, columnToCheck4, columnToCheck5, columnToCheck6, columnToCheck7, columnToCheck8 && sheet.getName() == sheetToSort) 
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("I'm busy sorting don't bother me.");
  }
}


function addNew_onEdit_Trigger()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('do_onEdit')
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

function timer_test()
{
  dispStatus('Loading.....','<script>var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,5000);function myTimer() { google.script.host.close();}</script>',200,100);
}

function associativeArrayTesting()
{
  var myA = {'man':'boy','woman':'girl','horse':'pony','hard':'gentle'};
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter a sentence using man, woman and horse.');
  var test = result.getResponseText();
  test = test.replace(/[\.]/,'');
  var wordsA = test.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0;i<wordsA.length;i++)
  {
    var key = wordsA[i];
    var value = myA[key];
    if(myA[key])
    {
      wordsA[i]=myA[wordsA[i]];
    }
  }
  dispStatus('My Word', wordsA.join(' '));
}

function SortQuestion(event)
{
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var ecol = editedCell.getColumn();

  var tableRange = "C16:84";
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);

  range.sort([function(x, y) {
    cx = x[5];
    cy = y[5];
    return (cx != "" && cy != "") || (cx == "" && cy == "") ? 0 : (cx == "" ? -1 : 1);
  }, {column: 4, ascending: false}]);
}function test()
{
  var prompt ='';
  if(prompt)
  {
    var S = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('7 comma separated values A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5]  A[6] is stop 1,1,1,1,1,1,1');
  }
  else
  {
    var S = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('7 comma separated values A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5] 1,1,1,1,1,1,1');
  }
    
  var A = S.getResponseText().split(',');
  
  if(A[0] = A[1] , A[2] , A[3] && A[4] == A[5])
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It\'s true.');
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It\'s false.');
  }
  if(A[6]==1)
  {
    test();
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}

function test1()
{
  //(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToCheck1, columnToCheck2, columnToCheck3 && sheet.getName() == sheetToSort)
  //var title = 'Evaluate (i==j, k, l && m==n) = result';
  var title = 'Evaluate (i==j, k, l) = result';
  var msg='';
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    var j=0;
    {
      var k=1;
      {
        var l=2;
        {
          var m=0;
          {
            var n=0;
            {
              if(n==j, k, l )
              {
                result='<span style="color:red;">true</span>';
              }
              else
              {
                result='<span style="color:black;">false</span>';
              }
              //msg += '( ' + i + ' == ' + j + ', ' + k + ', ' + l + ' && ' + m + ' == ' + n + ' ) = ' + result +'<br />';
              msg += '( ' + i + ' == ' + j + ', ' + k + ', ' + l + ' ) = ' + result +'<br />';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  dispStatus(title,msg,600,500);
}

function do_onEdit(e) 
{
  dispStatus('Do On Edit', 'At the beginning of do_onEdit',400,200);
  var sheetToSort = "Sheet2"; // name of sheet to be sorted
  var columnToCheck1 = 2; // column to check for edits
  var columnToCheck2 = 3; // second column to be checked for edits
  var columnToCheck3 = 6;
  var columnToCheck4 = 10;
  var columnToCheck5 = 11;
  var columnToCheck6 = 12;
  var columnToCheck7 = 13;
  var columnToCheck8 = 14;
  var columnToSortBy = 16; // column to sort by; A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var rangeToSort = "A1:P150"; // range of values to be sorted

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToCheck1, columnToCheck2, columnToCheck3, columnToCheck4, columnToCheck5, columnToCheck6, columnToCheck7, columnToCheck8 && sheet.getName() == sheetToSort) 
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("I'm busy sorting don't bother me.");
  }
}


function addNew_onEdit_Trigger()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('do_onEdit')
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

function timer_test()
{
  dispStatus('Loading.....','<script>var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,5000);function myTimer() { google.script.host.close();}</script>',200,100);
}

function associativeArrayTesting()
{
  var myA = {'man':'boy','woman':'girl','horse':'pony','hard':'gentle'};
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter a sentence using man, woman and horse.');
  var test = result.getResponseText();
  test = test.replace(/[\.]/,'');
  var wordsA = test.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0;i<wordsA.length;i++)
  {
    var key = wordsA[i];
    var value = myA[key];
    if(myA[key])
    {
      wordsA[i]=myA[wordsA[i]];
    }
  }
  dispStatus('My Word', wordsA.join(' '));
}

function SortQuestion(event)
{
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var ecol = editedCell.getColumn();

  var tableRange = "C16:84";
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);

  range.sort([function(x, y) {
    cx = x[5];
    cy = y[5];
    return (cx != "" && cy != "") || (cx == "" && cy == "") ? 0 : (cx == "" ? -1 : 1);
  }, {column: 4, ascending: false}]);
}
```

I stored some fragments in files because it takes a long time to run this script and so rather than taking the time to traverse all files each time I decided to store the info which I thought might be useful if I was looking for old stuff.  In realiity, I never  use the script.  You can ask question about it but I don't promise to answer them because it's been a long time since I've even looked at it.  It run's in Rhino but I haven't tested it in v8.